# How to add class on the div of modal-content in react bootstap modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am working with react-bootstrap and I need to add a class on modal-content div. I tried with `contentClassName` but it's not working. please suggest me what can I do?

```
<Modal
   show={showModal}
   onHide={this.closeModal}
   size={size && size}
   contentClassName="mx-auto" // this is not working
   dialogClassName={`mw-100 mx-15 ${dialogClassName ? dialogClassName : ''}` }
>
   {children}
</Modal>
```

Comment: @trkaplan yeah I appreciate your effort but I don't want to do like that you answered because I used global CSS which is used for multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

`contentClassName` prop will be available in the next version. (https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/5367 they have just merged this feature to the master and not released yet.)

But alternative solution would be using `dialogClass` (not `dialogClassName`) prop you can give a class name to the parent element and use it for styling the `modal-content` div. Or you can patch react-bootstrap manually using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)